# How can I extend ActiveRecord relations with new method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's imagine that I have simple ActiveRecord models like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :published_posts, -> { where(:published => true) }
end
```

And I want to create module `Reindexable` that will add a method called `reindex` into a base class. I want to be able to call this method in the 3 following ways:

```
Place.reindex
Place.reindex(Place.where(:published => true))
Place.where(:published => true).reindex
Category.first.places.reindex
```

Inside of this method I should be able to do something like this:

```
Reindexer.new(relation).reindex # how can I get relation here?
```

What is a correct way to do it in Ruby-on-Rails? How can I access current relation in all this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to include code into ActiveRecord_Relation class that is dynamically added into any AR classes.

In case you need to add .to_csv to all calls like MyModel.all.to_csv:

Model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ToCsv
end
```

You module that you want to include

```
module ToCsv
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  #  Dynamically including our Relation and extending current class
  #
  def self.included(child_class)
    child_class.const_get('ActiveRecord_Relation').include(RelationMethods)
    child_class.extend(ExtendMethods)
  end

  #  Instance Method
  #
  def to_csv(opts = {})
  end

  #  Module containing methods to be extended into the target
  #
  module ExtendMethods

    #  Allowing all child classes to extend ActiveRecord_Relation
    #
    def inherited(child_class)
      super + (child_class.const_get('ActiveRecord_Relation').include(RelationMethods) ? 1 : 0 )
    end
  end

  #  Holds methods to be added to relation class
  #
  module RelationMethods
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    #  Relation Method
    #
    def to_csv(opts = {})
    end
  end
end
```